# It is possible to run Tensorflow with elastic GPU in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, gpu

It is possible to run Tensorflow with elastic GPU (not CPU) in AWS?
If yes how?

Comment: In theory it should be possible (install cuda, tensorflow, specify device), but I am more concerned about the data throughput (limited by the eni network interface). Did you try it out? Where was the problem?

Comment: I tried to install it through anaconda, but it did not work